# Significance of 3 Teveis in Judaism

Tags: jewish-date-series, history, calendar

Is the 3nd day of the Month of Teveis significant in Judaism? Looking for answers as to what characteristics (historical, numerological or otherwise) that is commemorated by or significant to Judaism on this date. It can include both positive and negative significance. It can also include Yarzheits of well known personalities that are themselves significant to Judaism, or milestones in their lives (such as birthdays) that are currently or were celebrated within Judaism.

**Please cite / link your sources, if possible.**

All interesting answers will be up voted. Best answer will be accepted.

Answer (score 4):

Yarzheit of Rav Chaim Shmulevitz ZY'A - Rosh Yeshivas Mir

Answer (score 4):

From the [Luach Dvar B'Itoh תשע"א](http://hebrewbooks.org/51553) Page 454:

- The 3rd day of the Month of Teveis is sometimes the day after Chanuka. (Other years it's the 8th day of Chanuka)

  - The day after Chanuka is the first day in the year one can no longer bring Bikurim.([ביכורים א, ו](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00963.html#HtmpReportNum0005_L2)).
- The 3rd day of the Month of Teveis in the year 0002 is the day Hevel was killed by Kayin, according to some opinions. הריגת הבל לדעת ה"יערות דבש" דרוש י"ב‏
- Various Yahrzeits:

  - ברי"ת: נפ' ההק"ר אליעזר זאב (בההק"ר חיים) מבוטשעטש ‏
  - תרכ"ה: נפ' ההק"ר אברהם (בההק"ר יהודה צבי) מסטרטין‏
  - עת"ר: נפ' הגמ"ר יעקב הכהן (גדישה) ראב"ד ג'רבה, בעל "מעיל יעקב" ועוד,‏
  - תשל"ט: נפ' הגמ"ר חיים (ב"ר אלטר) הלוי שמואלביץ, ראש ישיבת מיר ‏

Answer (score 2):

Based on http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%92%27_%D7%91%D7%98%D7%91%D7%AA

**חגים ומועדים - Holidays**

- נר שמיני של חנוכה, "זאת חנוכה", בשנים בהן חודש כסלו חסר - "Zos Chanuka" or the eighth day of Hanukka (see also: [זאת חנוכה](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%96%D7%90%D7%AA_%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%94))) in some years (or the day after in others)

**אירועים היסטוריים - Historical events**

- **ה'תרצ"ג** – החל איכלוסה של קריית חיים, הראשונה בין הקריות שהוקמו בעמק
  זבולון, סמוך לחיפה
- **ה'תשמ"ג** - תאונת דרכים במעלה אפרים בה אוטובוס מטיילים מבית הספר אמירים
  בהרצליה הדרדר לתהום. חמש תלמידות קיפחו את חייהן
- **ה'תשס"ט** - ביום הרביעי למבצע עופרת יצוקה ארגון החמאס משגר לראשונה
  טילים לעבר באר שבע.

**נולדו - Births**

- ה'תרמ"ד - בן ציון דינור, שר, חבר כנסת, היסטוריון ומחנך (נפטר ה'תשל"ג
- ה'תר"ן - יצחק פוירינג, מנהיג ציוני מגרמניה (נפטר ה'תרצ"ח
- ה'תרפ"ח - שולמית אלוני, מקימת מנהיגת מרצ וחברת כנסת ושרה מטעמה (נפטרה
  בה'תשע"ד)
- ה'תשי"ג - אורי יהודה אריאל, חבר הכנסת מטעם האיחוד הלאומי
- ה'תשי"ז - שלום שמחון, פוליטיקאי ואיש ציבור ישראלי

**נפטרו - Deaths**

- ה'תקנ"א - יעקב פרנק, מנהיג שבתאי שהתנצר עם חסידיו
- ה'תר"ס - הרב יעקב חי עבו, ממנהיגי היישוב הישן בצפת
- ה'תקמ"ה - רבי דוד בן ברוך (הכהן אזו"ג)- רב ומקובל במרוקו, ביום פטירתו
  נערכת הילולה המונית על קברו.
- ה'תשל"ח – כלת פרס ישראל גרטרוד קראוס, רקדנית וכוריאוגרפית, מחלוצי
  המחול והבלט בארץ ישראל
- ה'תשל"ט - הרב חיים שמואלביץ, ראש ישיבת מיר (נולד ה'תרס"ב
- ה'תשס"ז - אורי דן, סופר ועיתונאי ישראלי (נולד ה'תרצ"ה
- ה'תרכ"ה - רבי אברהם בראנדוויין פון סטרעטין

Comment: To clarify, my −1 vote on this answer is primarily because it's in Hebrew. This is an English-language site. (That this is a reasonable answer to the question [probably indicates a problem with the question](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/468?m=19866504#19866504), but that's another issue.)